# Looking to retrieve Tweets from a certain time via Twitter api but my script returns 0 tweets

Tags: python, api, twitter

So I'm trying to get tweets from November 13 - November 15 that mention the word "paris" for a text-analysis project I'm working on.

When I try this code:

```
p = {"q":"paris", "since":"2015-11-13", "until":"2015-11-15", "lang":"en", "count":100}
paris = requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json",params=p,auth=oauth)
```

I get 0 statuses from `paris.json()`.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? And if possible I'd like to know how to do a search that looks "paris" or "breaking" or "terrorist" or "bombing" etc....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with what you're trying:

1. `since` is not a valid search parameter. There's [`since_id`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets#api-param-since_id) which requires the ID of a tweet to start from; not a date.
2. `until` is correct and requires a date which you have in the correct format but it has [this restriction](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets#api-param-search_until):

   > Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

Some things for you to check if you aren't sure you are authenticating correctly:

1. How have you generated your `auth` token? Hopefully you're using "[Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only)".
2. You're already using the 'requests' package so you could use the [OAuth 1 workflow](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib#the-oauth-1-workflow) from that.
3. Look at the response headers with `paris.headers` to make sure you aren't getting some other error which is being ignored.